# How can I covert an object to an array in php

Tags: php, oop, laminas

How can I convert an object to an array in php? For example, here I want to convert the $result variable into an array. Here is the code:

````
$statement = $adapter->createStatement('SELECT * FROM `users`');
$result    = $statement->execute();
$result = new JsonModel($result);
$result = array($result);
var_dump($result);
return ($result);
```

It produces the following output. 
array(1) { [0]=> object(Laminas\View\Model\JsonModel)#160 (8) { ["captureTo":protected]=> NULL ["jsonpCallback":protected]=> NULL ["terminate":protected]=> bool(true) ["children":protected]=> array(0) { } ["options":protected]=> array(0) { } ["template":protected]=> string(0) "" ["variables":protected]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(13) "J. K. Rowling" ["deleted"]=> string(1) "0" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(19) "George R. R. Martin" ["deleted"]=> string(1) "0" } [2]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["name"]=> string(16) "J. R. R. Tolkien" ["deleted"]=> string(1) "0" } [3]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["name"]=> string(12) "Donald Trump" ["deleted"]=> string(1) "0" } } ["append":protected]=> bool(false) } }
````

Comment: `$result = (array)$result;` or even `$result = (array)new JsonModel($data);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver He said he tried that.

Comment: If typecasting doesn't work, the class probably has private properties and accessor methods to extract them. You'll need to write custom code that gets all the properties you want using these methods, and puts them into an array. There's no general answer to this.

Comment: @Barmar They didn't do it properly. Or better question is what does _it doesn't work_ mean.

Comment: Show your code that uses typecasting, and show a `var_dump()` of the result.

Comment: `$statement = $adapter->createStatement('SELECT * FROM users'); 
$result = $statement->execute(); 
$result = new JsonModel($result); 
$result = (array)$result; 
return ($result); `
if I typecast it, it shows an error. "Laminas\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "resource/resource/get-list"; resolver could not resolve to a file"

Comment: @MahmudulHasan update your question instead of pasting code in comment.

Comment: You may need to use methods of `Laminas` to do this.

Comment: I think the answer to this highly depends on what JsonModel looks like, and how you want your array to look like.

Comment: Hi This is how the JsonModel look like. ** [{"id":"1","name":"J. K. Rowling","deleted":"0"},{"id":"2","name":"George R. R. Martin","deleted":"0"},{"id":"3","name":"J. R. R. Tolkien","deleted":"0"},{"id":"4","name":"Donald Trump","deleted":"0"}] **
I want them as an associative array. Sorry for my unclean question.

Comment: pls to not try to cast an array to json to an whatsoever object. Use your framework (laminas) logic or maybe go with PDO (parameter $class_name in fetching methods)

Answer (score 1):

there are a couple of hydrators available in the PHP world.
You can use them standalone or with an ORM like doctrine.
For example, look at this:

1. https://packagist.org/packages/laminas/laminas-hydrator
2. https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/doctrine-module

If you use Laminas without Dotrine, I'd go with 1

Answer (score 0):

the dirty trick would be...

```
$result    = $statement->execute();
$Array = json_decode(json_encode($result),true);
```

Comment: In this case it shows this error message:

**Laminas\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "resource/resource/get-list"; resolver could not resolve to a file**

Comment: this feels like a frontend error not a data structure error. You might need to include more of your code in order for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply we can get object to array like this:

$result    = $statement->execute();
$Array = (array)$result;